# Bone heat weighting problem, texture paint problem, blending model

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

Hello fellow Blenders...

I am attempting to make my first model ever, however I am having some difficulties. I hope you can help me with the following.

Question 1:

Here is the link to the blend file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvh9ajtpoxewl6o/leprechaunnotconnecting01.blend?dl=0

I first selected the object, then selected the armature, I pressed CRTL P, Set parent to - armature deform - with automatic weights, however I get the message: bone heat weighting failed to find solution for 1 or more bones. The envelope method seems to work but it lacks precision. When I bow the elbow afterwards, pretty much the entire model moves a bit.

Question 2:
Is it possible to unselect bones for your armature connecting to your mesh? Or does it need to be the entire armature at all times?

Question 3:
As you might have seen my leprechaun has a line in the middle. This is also visible in the 3D rendering software in the game. I copied it's other half. Is it possible to blend out this effect from splitting? So yes, how do I do this?

Question 4: When I texture paint my mesh, it seems to paint on 4 sides at the same time. Is there any solution to this? (try it on the download)

Much appreciated in advantage! Please take into consideration I am very new to this.

Comment: The format of this Q&A site only permits one question, this appeaers to be 4 disctinct questions.  Can you rework it so that it falls within our guideline. [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model is very messy. Firstly append it to a new file to fix some viewport messed up settings and make it an appropriate size.

[image]

Secondly, automatic weights freak out because of the inverted normal, recalculate them.

[image]

Thirdly, clean up weights and pose and reapply parenting.

[image]

The model is still a mess

[image]

It is better to take the original and optimize it. https://free3d.com/3d-model/leprechaun-v1--543940.html

Make him T-pose for better results.

[image]

Optimize geometry. Better to remesh it. But I won't .

[image]

You can also unwrap and bake normals.

[image]

[image]

The automatic weights are not very suited for this. It might be better to use something more advanced, which is actually intended as an auto rigger. For example https://www.mixamo.com/

[image]

Choose T-pose to export

[image]

Or paid addon for Blender: https://blendermarket.com/products/auto-rig-pro But be prepared to still fix something manually.

And finally: do not let the frustration beat you

[image]

and have fun

[image]

Animations from Mixamo

[image]

Comment: Thanks Unwave, that certainly helped a lot! Unfortunately I was unable to use the rig in the game due to translation issues from the .blend to .dae. The items and the head were certainly useful, learned a lot about resizing, texture paint and the weights. Here is the use in the game (with a recolored body): https://www.dropbox.com/s/ei2xscj5veqbfiv/Naamloos-1.jpg?dl=0 .